# why is tedpermission not added?

Tags: android

I tried to use tedpermission in my custom android app. So I added tedpermission implementation in my code. I thought I could use permissionListener by adding tedpermission implementation. But I can't use that. Why?
here is my code in build.gradle(module).
dependencies {

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.3'// I added tedpermission here
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you see the recent documentation: https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission with different gradle library names?

Answer (score 2):

In the **build.gradle (app module)**, dependencies should be as below I think.

**`implementation 'io.github.ParkSangGwon:tedpermission-normal:3.3.0'`**

Answer (score 2):

Also use `create()` method not "with"

```
TedPermission.create()
                .setPermissionListener(permissionListener)
                .setRationaleMessage("Messages")
                .setDeniedMessage("Messages")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
```